# How to define the base64 content encoding in a REST API?

Tags: rest, api, http, base64, mime-types

I would like to do a REST resource that could be represented as:

- PDF (binary for download);
- JSON (with structured data);
- PDF (base64 encode)

My expectation is to create a URL like this:

```
http://api.mybank.com/accounts/{accountId}/statement?fromDate=2019-11
```

The `Accept` header as `'application/json'` will return the statement information.

The `Accept` header as `'application/pdf'` will return the statement in a PDF binary file.

And PDF encoded as `base64`? How I define this?

[**Content-Transfer-Encoding**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#page-14) is not an HTTP, but email header.

[**Transfer-Encoding**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) is used only for compression.

Comment: What's the purpose of base64-encoding a PDF?

Comment: What have you tried? The policy here is to show the work done. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JulianReschke, some of my users prefer to receive files (any) in base64 format because their applications are already coded do manipulate this format.

Comment: @hfontanez, thak you. The question here is more conceptual. I don't have or need code yet. The questions is more about: use query string, use custom header, use a custom mime type etc. and why one of these approaches would be more RESTfull than other. Or may be, find out some argument against encode files as base64 in RESTfull APIs.

Comment: The information about "Content-Transfer-Encoding" and "Transfer-Encoding" is because I altread find using this headers as answers in other similar questions, but using them for that is not correct.

Comment: A good reason not to encode in base64 is that it increases the content size. *why* do users prefer to receive base64 encoded content? Did you ask?

Comment: @JulianReschke, because some legacy systems do this way. I don't know the history.

Comment: Not convinced. :-)

Comment: I prefer to don't do that, but if somebody asks for this return type, I will recomend to use application/json as mime type plus query string "?pdfBase64=true".